# Getting Missing cookbook exception While running file locally in chef-client

Tags: chef-client

i'm using below command to run file locally in chef-client
[root@ip- cookbook]# chef-client -zr "recipe[test-cookbook::test-recipe]"

also i tried below command, but getting same exception
chef-client -z -o test-cookbook

Please help me with above Query.

i'm trying to run those file locally in chef-client but not able to do so